# TWiki, Mail and Proxies & gmail

Tags: gmail, wiki, twiki

Could someone guide me through the TWiki mail configuration?

I would like to set up gmail account to send emails from twiki.

Net::SMTP is already installed.

Thanks,
LG

Answer (score 0):

in my foswiki setups, I use ssmtp, which relays to the servers.

however, http://foswiki.org/Development/SupportSSLandTLSforSMTP and http://foswiki.org/Support/Faq69 may well help you get it working

(SSL/TLS was added to foswiki in 1.1.4)

Sven